# Laravel 4.2 Eloquent Dynamic Query

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, orm, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve a collection of items via my Item Model based on 8+ optional inputs.

I will have named optional inputs such as 'Item Name', 'Item Code', 'Item Colour' and would like to be able to use only the completed inputs as where clauses on my query.

I found a [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-create-a-dynamic-query-using-eloquent) that I thought explained how I should be able to achieve this however I can't seem to make it work.

I had imagined that code something like:

```
$query = Item::select();

if(Input::has('name')) {
    $query->where('ItemName', Input::get('name'));
}

if(Input::has('code')) {
    ....
}

$query->get();
```

I tested my presumptions with the following code.

If I use the following code:

```
$query = Item::select()->where('ItemCode', '0605')->get();
```

I get a collection of 5 items returned as expected but if I use the following code:

```
$query = Item::select();
$query->where('ItemCode', '0605')->get();
```

I get an Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder object returned and not a collection of items as I would expect.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or advise me on what the correct way to achieve this is?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin apologies for not making this clearer, I've amended my question to try and demonstrate what I was hoping to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crazy thought, but just to be sure. Maybe you want this?

```
$query = Item::select();

if(Input::has('name')) {
    $query->where('ItemName', Input::get('name'))
}

if(Input::has('code')) {
    ....
}

$query = $query->get();
```

Comment: Cracked it, how strange ,I'm annoyed that I hadn't tried this!
Thanks very much!